# Does NGINX support PCRE2 Extended replacement processing?

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

I need to do some really complex rewrites and I would like not to have to repeat myself too much. PCRE2 conditional substitutions would allow me to do so, but I can't seem to make them work in nginx. Is it just not supported or am I doing something wrong?

These are the rewrites I'd like to unify.

```
    rewrite /intro/(es|en)-(es|uk)/pageA /$1-$2/pageB/;
    rewrite /intro/(es|en)_(es|uk)/pageA /$1-$2/pageB/;
    rewrite /intro/(es|en|uk)/pageA /$1/pageB/;
```

Answer (score 7):

No, because in NGINX configurations you are *not using PCRE substitutions* to combine regex-captured values, irrespective of what regular expression engine is used (PCRE or PCRE2).

NGINX simply takes the captured values from regexes, and turns those into NGINX variables. `rewrite` and other directives then let you use these *variables* to combine these into new strings, using standard NGINX expressions (wherever the documentation states the value *can contain text, variables, and their combination*).

So, no, you can't use any PCRE2 substitution features, unfortunately.

Perhaps you could use a [`map` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) instead, to set a new variable based on regexes:

```
http {
    # map can only be used at the http context
    map $uri $intro_lang {
        ~^/intro/(es|en)[-_](es|uk)/    "$1-$2"
        ~^/intro/(es|en|uk)/            "$1"
        default                         "uk"
    }
    server {
        # rewrite goes in the server context, or inside a location directive.
        rewrite /intro/[^/]*/pageA /intro/$intro_lang/pageB/;
    }
}
```

Each `~`-prefixed entry in the map is a regular expression, and if it matches, the named variable `$intro_lang` is set to the value for that expression. The value here can use variables, so the `$1` and `$2` position captures are used here.

Note that `map` goes in the `http` context; if you are using a distribution that uses include files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d` then those are usually included in a `http {}` context already and so the top-level of those included files are the right context for `map` directives.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. nginx currently supports only the original PCRE library.

Comment: It doesn't matter what PCRE revision is used for regexes, as NGINX doesn't use PCRE or PCRE2 to run substitutions. NGINX turns captures into variables and those are then used in NGNIX string expressions, these are **not** processed using the regex substitution engine.